# Center 2 divs horizontally without a wrapper

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want to simply center 2 divs horizontally regardless of the screen width and without using a wrapper. I have the following simple code:

```
#div1 {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#div2 {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

I created the following fiddle for illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/axe89/

- The reason I don't want to use a wrapper is that I want to make a cross platform website and if I define a width for the wrapper it will break mobile screen.

Comment: You don't have to define a width for the wrapper though ..

Comment: if i don't define a width for the wrapper it will be useless as the wrapper will fill the screen and the child DIVs will not center

Comment: No, you're wrong about that: http://jsfiddle.net/axe89/2/

Comment: haven't thought of using text-align:center. Instead tried margin:0 auto; Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

@setek has the solution above, just wanted to add this quick rule of thumb:

To horizontally center `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` items, use `text-align:center;`.

To horizontally center `display:block` items, use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

as alluded to by setek, you can define a container for your divs, with a width of 100% so that it scales with the screen/device width. Also set its text align to center to achieve your desired effect.

```
#container{text-align:center;width:100%;}
```

here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axe89/3/)

and for slightly modified markup and css - http://jsfiddle.net/axe89/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use css margin properties.

```
margin-left:40%
```

to the first div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
text-align: center;
```

to the body tag or to whatever you are planning to wrap the divs with.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5C67h/)